# DRF get current user details

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to get the current logged in user's details:

**views.py**

```
class UserData(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    def get(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(self.request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['id', 'email', 'valid_email', 'nickname', 'name', 'date_of_birth', 'city', 'country', 'date_joined']
```

When i'm trying to access the url i get this error:

```
AttributeError at /core/user-data/  
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `email` on serializer `UserSerializer`. 
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `AnonymousUser` instance. 
Original exception text was: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'email'.
```

The thing is that i am logged in. What could cause the error?

Comment: change your permissions class to `IsAuthenticated`

Comment: i've changed it and now it gives me {"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}, if i am logged in the admin shouldn't it return the serializer data?

Comment: read the [doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/) and check is all your settings are correct

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when you are making this request, you are unauthenticated, which makes the self.request.user a AnonymousUser.

you can try to verify that by doing `assert request.user.is_authenticated==True`. It should return False.

Here's a link to [Django AnonymousUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#anonymoususer-object) and a link to [Django Authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests)