# How to get details of Current User in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm working on my API based on Django Rest Framework. I've managed to add current user automatically on POST request via HiddenField. Now I want to return some additional information about current user within the GET request for blog post.

I've tried to access this data from `CurrentUserDefault()` and via `source='author.username'`. First one doesn't work at all, the second option breaks on Save, because author wasn't provided in request.

```
class BlogSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    # author_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source=serializers.CurrentUserDefault().name)
    # author_username = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='author.username')
```

How can I access details of Current User and append it as read-only fields?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DRF get current user details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47081125/drf-get-current-user-details)

Comment: @martbln Not really, author field works fine, but I can't get any additional details about logged-in user. I add authentication details to my requests, so that's not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serialize `user` information, but in a read_only manner. This could do the job :

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (<what you want>)

class BlogSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    author = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
```